# Why HikariCP creates so many idle connections in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, database-connection, postgresql-9.4, hikaricp

I have a JSP application running on glassfish5 with postgresql as the database service. To manage connections I have opted for HikariCP as shown below

```
 config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", host);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", port);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", database);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("assumeMinServerVersion", postrgesVersion);
    config.setMinimumIdle(100);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
    config.setAutoCommit(false);
    config.setIdleTimeout(3000);

    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

and the implementation with datasource this way

```
  public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

when i run the following query in pgAdmin

```
select datname,pid,usename,client_addr,client_port,backend_start,query,state from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'db_name' AND client_addr='10.1.0.56'
```

I get the following results with many connections which don't have any query in them as shown in the photo below

[image]

After a few seconds postgres complains that there are too many connetions. Has anyone ever experience anything like this, please help.

Comment: This size of your pool is insane.  Please read [About Pool Sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Answer (score 2):

`setMinimumIdle(100)` will create 100 connection at startup which is unnecessary / bad practice.

You should lower your idle Connection and maximum pool size according to [Hikari connection pool grows to maximum size at start](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/256) answer

> If you have 3 active nodes (and 1 backup), and in production each node normally needs 5-6 connections, possibly set maximumPoolSize to 20, minimumIdle to 2, and idleTimeout to something like 2 minutes (120000ms).

So in your case change two lines :

```
config.setMinimumIdle(2);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
```

Comment: I still get some blank idle connetions and they don't close up

Comment: does glassfish has anything to do with these problems